# Copy string to clipboard natively python 3

Tags: python, windows, clipboard

I looked for a long time for a good method to put a string on the clipboard, using only the directories included in python. I tried

```
import subprocess
def copy2clip(txt):
    cmd='echo '+txt.strip()+'|clip'
    return subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
```

and then calling

```
copy2clip('text')
```

However this seemed to add an extra line to the text on the clipboard.

I also tried the Tkinter method, but it just made the python window crash when I tried to paste.

I am running python 3.5.2 on windows 10.

Comment: There's no need to use the shell, which is especially bad here since `shell=True` doesn't use the `/U` option that makes cmd's internal commands output Unicode. Instead the echoed output is getting best-fit encoded to the console or ANSI codepage. Consider using the new `run` function instead, e.g. `subprocess.run(['clip.exe'], input=txt.strip().encode('utf-16'), check=True)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I used

```
import subprocess
txt = "Save to clipboard!"
subprocess.run(['clip.exe'], input=txt.strip().encode('utf-16'), check=True)
```

worked perfectly. Thanks @eryksun for commenting this answer.

Comment: This didn't work for me. When i pasted a multiline string into ipython it said "ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes". Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a native solution too but the ones I found had me struggled with UTF-16 Encoding and including a BOM.
I solved it with:

```
import subprocess    
subprocess.run(['clip.exe'], input=txt.encode('UTF-16LE'), check=True)
```

on Windows